# Add items to combobox in list

Tags: c#

I have a list

```
List<Control> inputBoxes = new List<Control>();
```

where I have added comboboxes and textboxes.

I can set the text property with                 `inputBoxes[0].GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(inputBoxes[0], "ABC", null);`
but how can I add items to the comboboxes and select them?

Can I use `inputBoxes[0].GetType().GetMethod()` somehow?

Comment: why not just `Add(..)`, why do you use reflection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use reflection to simply set a property?

You can use this which is much more efficient and less error-prone:

```
inputBoxes.OfType<TextBox>().ElementAt(0).Text = "ABC";
```

If you want to add items to one (or multiple) ComboBoxes:

```
var combos =  inputBoxes.OfType<ComboBox>();
foreach(ComboBox combo in combos)
{
    // add items here or set their DataDource, for example:
    string[] installs = new string[]{"Typical", "Compact", "Custom"};
    combo.Items.AddRange(installs);
}
```

Note that you need to add `using System.Linq` for `OfType`